# (lldb) - How pause an application and debug at the actual running UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lldb

I'm new at `lldb` debugging and hope you can help me :)

basically I want to express some functions as e.g.

```
(lldb) expr device.up()
(lldb) expr device.down()
```

to watch the changing behaviour of the UI at the Simulator. (lot of animations..)

I can achieve this when i set a breakpoint at my `UIViewController`, and then type the commands. But after pressing start again it waits for a delegate and i only can pause it manually to get the debug console again. And there comes my question: Is it possible, when I pause the application, to debug at the same environment (of the specific, activ `UIViewController`) as before where I set the breakpoint?

I'm glad for your tips and lldb experience and pls write if my question is unclear! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stack frame you were evaluating expression in is still on the stack somewhere, you can select that thread & frame:

```
(lldb) thread 5
(lldb) frame 7
```

then run the expression.  If the frame is no longer on the stack, you can't do that.  If the expression you were evaluating refer to local variables, you won't be able to recover them, the memory they occupied is gone.

But you can store values away in lldb convenience variables.  For instance, if you were using C++ and "device" was a  reference to an object of type `SomeType`, you could do:

```
(lldb) expr SomeType *$reference_to_device = &device
```

Then later you could do:

```
(lldb) expr $reference_to_device->up()
```

Capturing the address isn't going to keep the object alive, however, something actually in your program will have to do that.

Comment: Hey thx for your answer! The problem is that i don't know which thread/frame the actual ViewController is. Should the VC not be on the stack if he is actually running?

Comment: I'm not a UIKit/AppKit expert.  But as I understand it, the UI objects respond to events by having their event handler's invoked.  They do their response, then go back to sleep till another event wakes them.  So a given ViewController will only have methods on the stack during the course of their event response, then they will not be on the stack.  OTOH, it is also true that for both AppKit & UIKit, all the user interaction callbacks get handled on the main thread, so finding which thread they are on should be straightforward.

Comment: that explains a lot - i think i have to set a breakpoint to access the methods in a easy way... thank you for your time, helped me a lot!! :)